# how to get esp32 ip address ,which is being connected to local network

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, iot

I need to know the IP address of ESP32 on the local network(without printing ip on serial monitor ). The idea is to do mDNS or UDP broadcast to send the IP to the android application. The app will then use that IP to do the communication. Is there someone who has already done it?

Comment: You have already answered it yourself.  `The idea is to do mDNS...` - that is exactly what mDNS is for. You don't know the IP address, so you look it up with mDNS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You configure mDNS (as you already suggested in your question...!) and the client device then queries mDNS to find the device by the name you allocated it.

Look at the ESPmDNS library examples for how to use mDNS.

Edit: if you really want the IP, you can do `WiFi.localIP()` (station mode) or `WiFi.softAPIP()` (access point mode).